# A reported question which is not even a question

Tags: questions

Swan, Practical English Usage (p.250)
**3. yes/no questions: He asked if ...**
Yes/no questions are reported with if or whether (for the difference, see 621).

The driver asked if/whether I wanted the town centre.
I don't know if/whether I can help you.
**In reported questions, we do not use a present tense after if to talk about the
future.

I'm not sure if I'll see her tomorrow.** (NOT ... if J see her tomorrow.)
How come "I'm not sure if I'll see her tomorrow" is a reported yes/no question? It does not look like a question, reported or not.

Comment: _If_ in this context is equivalent to _whether_, which is the _Wh_-word for embedded _yes/no_ questions. Both refer to a 50/50 possibility; that's what _yes/no_ is all about.

Answer (score 1):

A reported question is a sentence that refers to a question. Sometimes the report will explicitly use a word like "asked" to refer to the original question, as in your first example "The driver asked ...".

But the question can also be implicit. You're describing a state of mind where some condition is in question.

> I'm not sure if I'll see her tomorrow.

corresponds to the question

> Will I see her tomorrow?

If you want to see it in the first form, it's similar to saying:

> I'm asking myself if I'll see her tomorrow.